# MongoDB - filter condition and 3-deep objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to get all the docs where `translations.proposedTranslation` exists, but `translations.proposedTranslation.translator` doesn't, in at least one of the objects in the `translations` array.

These docs **should** be selected:

```
{
    translations: [{
        language: "spanish",
        proposedTranslation: {
            user: "123456789"
        }
    }]
}
//and
{
    translations: [{
        language: "spanish",
        proposedTranslation: {
            user: "123456789"
        }
    }, {
        language: "french",
        proposedTranslation: {
            user: "123456789",
            translator: "987654321"
        }
    }]
}
```

This one should **not**:

```
{
    translations: [{
        language: "spanish",
        proposedTranslation: {
            user: "123456789",
            translator: "987654321"
        }
    }]
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$expr: {
    $gte: [
        {
            $size: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$translations",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $ne: ["$$this.proposedTranslation", null]
                            },
                            {
                                $eq: ["$$this.proposedTranslation.translator", null]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        1
    ]
}
```

However, this returns no docs. I think it's because of `$eq: ["$$this.proposedTranslation.translator", null]`, since it works as it should if I omit that line. Is there something I need to change since it's a 3-deep object?

Comment: I doubt that the depth of the hierarchy should matter. You say the `$eq` `null` part is the problem. What happens if you create an example where you're testing for equality with `null` but it's not deep in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed it for me, since I found out that the problem was actually the way I was checking if a field is null or not:

```
$expr: {
    $gte: [
        {
            $size: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$translations",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $ifNull: ["$$this.proposedTranslation", false]
                            },
                            {
                                $not: [{ $ifNull: ["$$this.proposedTranslation.translator", false] }]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        1
    ]
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. In SQL, `NULL = NULL` evaluates to false. If you want to check whether a thing is null, you have to do something like `proposedTranslation IS NOT NULL`.